# Does the statement, "every number other than zero has a multiplicative inverse" require two variables?

Tags: logic

Can the English sentence, "every number other than zero has a multiplicative inverse" be
written as
$∀x(x \ne 0 → x \cdot 1/x = 1)$

Comment: x factorial is never zero.  Use $\ne$ for the not-equals operator.  `!=` is a programming language thing.

Comment: For the statement in the title, I would say that you are still using two "variables": $x$ and $1/x$.

Comment: For the statement in the question, the short answer is no.

Comment: $1/x$ multiplied by $x$ equals one from the definition of $1/x$. If you can write $1/x$ then you don't need to check if this multiplication is equal to one.

Comment: The english sentence has a *distinct* subject "every number other than $0$" so that requires a variable, and it has a *distinct* object "has a multiplicative" inverse. That requires second variable. Now you *can* notate the variable in terms of the first such as $x$ and $y_x$ or $x$ and $x^{-1}$ or even $x$ or $\frac 1x$. However I'd advise against that latter two as they come with "emotional baggage" but even if you do you *MUST* consider $\frac 1x$ a *second* and different variable than $x$. (so if you did the you'd say $\forall x(x\ne0\to\exists\frac1x:x\cdot \frac 1x=1)$. (But I wouldn't)

Answer (score 3):

I would denote the statement as:

$$\forall x (x\neq 0\implies\exists y \text{ such that } y\cdot x = x\cdot y = 1)$$

As Mateo already said, you cannot write $1/x$ before you show that it even exists. In the case of my notation, you can conclude $y=1/x$.

Answer (score 0):

What does $1/x$ mean? In order to write your sentence, you assume the existence of a function $f(x)=1/x$, which you assert has a certain property ($x \cdot 1/x =1$). This is different from the sentence you want to write, which says that for any nonzero number, there is another number such that the two numbers multiply to 1.